# No Arbitrage condition for assets with different time frame

Tags: finance-mathematics, asset-pricing, no-arbitrage-theory

In the classic literature, one always assumes that the assets in the market are all available from the very beginning ($t=0$). And under such condition the market is arbitrage free iff there exists an equivalent local martingale measure. But what if there is some asset that is not available for trading until a strict positive amount of time (especially when this is a stopping time?)

Specifically, consider the following model with two assets: $S_1$ is able to trade in [0,1], whereas the other asset $S_2$ is able to trade only in $[\tau,1]$ where $\tau$ is a stopping time. Is the existence of an equivalent local martingale measure sufficient to exclude arbitrage? In general I think not. For instance if the two assets are correlated (like $S_2(1) = 2S_1(1)$ a.s.). Then you need extra condition that $S_2(\tau) = 2S_1(\tau)$ to ensure no arbitrage.

I wonder what exactly one needs more to make sure the model is arbitrage-free in general? Is there any literature